# Snakemake subworkflow result is not found if I specify a target in subfolder

Tags: snakemake

Let's regard two snakefiles, one main file and one subworkflow:

./Snakefile:

```
subworkflow sub:
    workdir: "."
    snakemake: "subworkflow/Snakefile"

rule all:
    input: sub("subresult")
```

./subworkflow/Snakefile:

```
rule sub_all:
    output: "subresult"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

This code works pretty well. Now let's introduce a small change: substitute "subresult" with "./subresult" in the main file:
`output: "./subresult"`
That still works, but if I make the same change in the subworkflow, I get the exception:

```
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce subresult
```

The same exception is thrown if I specify any other subfolder in the output of the subworkflow's rule:

```
subworkflow sub:
    workdir: "."
    snakemake: "subworkflow/Snakefile"

rule all:
    input: sub("ANY_PATH/subresult")
```

```
rule sub_all:
    output: "ANY_PATH/subresult"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

I guess this is not a normal behavior. Is there anything wrong in my code? Is there a way to specify subworkflow's target in a subfolder?

**OS**: Windows + MinGW

**Python** 3.6.5

**Snakemake** 5.4.5, 5.2

**Update:**

I tried the example provided by @JeeYem, and even *data* subdirectory didn't work on my system. After some investigation I found that this is a platform-specific problem for Windows or Windows/MinGW combination. Below is the code that works and shows the problem (I left the original code commented for comparison):

File Snakefile:

```
subworkflow otherworkflow:
    workdir:
        "."
    snakefile:
        "kingmaker.Snakefile"

rule all:
    input:
        otherworkflow('data/a.txt')
```

Subworkflow file kingmaker.Snakefile:

```
rule write_file:
    output:
        #'data/a.txt'
        'data\\a.txt'
    shell:
        #'touch {output}'
        'touch data/a.txt'
```

Note that I even cannot use {output} variable in the shell section.

I will submit a ticket to the Snakemake repository.

Comment: This is very well written first post! Great Job!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing, my guess would be you are using `./` in the beginning of those paths in `input` or/and `output`, which is what causing the problem. I am not sure of the exact reason, but snakemake seems to point to the cause of the problem (see end of the answer).

In my example scripts as shown below, I can use subdirectory `data` without any problem in both Snakefiles. However, if I use `./data` (ie. `./` in the beginning of subdirectory), snakemake has trouble working properly.

File `Snakefile`:

```
subworkflow otherworkflow:
    workdir:
        "."
    snakefile:
        "kingmaker.Snakefile"

rule all:
    input:
        otherworkflow('data/a.txt')
```

Subworkflow file `kingmaker.Snakefile`:

```
rule write_file:
    output:
        'data/a.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```

In fact, if you run the subworkflow by itself (ie. `snakemake -s kingmaker.Snakefile`) with `./` in the beginning of the output path, snakemake strongly discourages its usage with this warning:

```
Relative file path './data/a.txt' starts with './'. 
This is redundant and strongly discouraged. 
It can also lead to inconsistent results of the file-matching approach used by Snakemake. 
You can simply omit the './' for relative file paths.
```

I am using snakemake `v5.4.0` on mac.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the question accordingly.